# Finding number of identical groups

Tags: r

Consider a clustering problem, where the true class labels are known (say `g`).

Suppose, `p` denotes the predicted cluster labels (can be obtained by any clustering approach).

So, both `g` and `p` splits the data set in some groups, though the number of groups need not be same in two cases.

Among these two sets of groups, in some cases one group by `g` will be identical to another group by `p`, though their labels in two cases may be different. I want to find the number of such groups, i.e. I want to find the number of cases where the clustering method is able to detect a class perfectly.

I understand this is not a standard way to evaluate clustering (Rand Index, Dunn Index, etc. are recommended), but I am interested in this. I also understand that this number will be very small in most of the real life data, may be even `0`, but the data set I am currently working with has a large number (around 1500) of classes, with highest number of observations in one class being at most 15. So, in this case, this number is likely to be quite high.

Here is a reproducible example and my attempt (working) at the solution:

```r
# true labels
g <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4)

# predicted labels
p <- c(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2)

# correctly detected groups
n_correct <- 2 # (1st class and 3rd cluster), (4th class and 2nd cluster)

# attempt
distinct_class_labels <- unique(x = g)
counter <- 0
for (i in seq_along(along.with = distinct_class_labels))
{
  cluster_labels_of_obs_in_ith_class <- subset(x = p,
                                               subset = (g == distinct_class_labels[i]))
  unique_cluster_labels_of_obs_in_ith_class <- unique(x = cluster_labels_of_obs_in_ith_class)
  if (length(x = unique_cluster_labels_of_obs_in_ith_class) == 1)
  {
    class_labels_of_obs_in_this_cluster <- subset(x = g,
                                                  subset = (p == unique_cluster_labels_of_obs_in_ith_class))
    if (length(x = unique(x = class_labels_of_obs_in_this_cluster)) == 1)
    {
      counter <- (counter + 1)
    }
  }
}
counter
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This works correctly, but it takes time (and I do not like this method). I suppose one can use `dplyr::group_by` with both `g` and `p` separately and somehow compare the groups of these two objects. I guess there are other better approaches to this and I will highly appreciate such answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are also interested in the combination of the correctly detected groups you can try this

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(g = g, p=p) %>%
  distinct(g,p) %>% # unique combinations of g and p
  add_count(g, name="g_count") %>% # count how often each class/label occurs in g and p. When it is unambiguous assigned it should be 1
  add_count(p, name="p_count") %>%
  filter(g_count == 1 & p_count == 1) %>%
  select(g,p)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      g     p
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     4     2
```

The number of rows (you can use `nrow()`) will give you the number of correctly detected groups

Comment: Can you please add some explanation? I think it uses the fact that for perfect detection of a class by some cluster, neither the class label nor the cluster label can be occurring with any other cluster or class respectively. Is that so?

Comment: Exactly, you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Convert `g` and `p` to `factor` with `levels` specified based on their occurrence in the vector and count the frequencies that match.

```
sum(table(factor(p, levels = unique(p))) == table(factor(g, levels = unique(g))))
#[1] 2
```

To understand, see

```
table(factor(p, levels = unique(p)))

#3 1 4 2 
#3 4 2 1 
table(factor(g, levels = unique(g)))

#1 2 3 4 
#3 3 3 1
```

We can ignore the labels (as the group labels are not same) and focus only on frequency. We can see that the first and fourth value have the same frequency hence, the count 2.

If you want to find out which groups are similar, you can do

```
inds <- table(factor(p, levels = unique(p))) == table(factor(g, levels = unique(g)))
unique(p)[inds]
#[1] 3 2
unique(g)[inds]
#[1] 1 4
```

This says that group 3 in `p` is similar to group 1 in `g` and same for 2 and 4 respectively.

---

Before solving it using `table` , I did it with `split` although the underlying logic is the same.

```
sum(lengths(split(p, factor(p, levels = unique(p)))) == 
    lengths(split(g, factor(g, levels = unique(g)))))
```

---

**EDIT**

If there is a chance of class imbalance we need to combine the levels to include all. For example,

```
g1 <- c(g, 5)
p1 <- c(p, 1)


sum(table(factor(p1, levels = unique(c(p1, g1)))) ==  
    table(factor(g1, levels = unique(c(g1, p1)))))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Suppose there are more clusters than there are classes (or vice versa). Then, will it be possible to do this line: `table(factor(p, levels = unique(p))) == table(factor(g, levels = unique(g)))`?

Comment: @yarnabrina We need to combine the levels in that case. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that'll work. But I can think of another scenario. Suppose `g2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5)` and `p2 <- c(13, 13, 11, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 11, 12, 11)`. Then, you'll get `6`, where it should be `2`. Do I need to modify the `labels` argument for that?

Comment: @yarnabrina yes, in that case change them to same `labels` `g3 <- factor(g2, labels = letters[seq_len(length(unique(g2)))]); p3 <- factor(p2, labels = letters[seq_len(length(unique(p2)))])` and then use the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Just one final clarification: is `letters` necessary?

Comment: No, you can use anything. The point being the labels should be the same for both of them.